# What would be the most efficient way to create high energy states in quantum fields with 3.76E+26 eV

Tags: quantum-field-theory

This is the energy nesccessary to create a bottom quark, the most massive (in the sense of mass, not size, this is a way of referring to *mass*) particle. I usedE=m(c*c) to calculate the value. I'm curious to know how to do this, if you could create high energy states in quantum fields with up to this energy, you could "print" fermions into exotic structures for interesting research.

Comment: You must have made some mistake because the mass of the bottom quark is 4 GeV.

Comment: This is 4.18 GeV (bottom quark mass) multiplied by lightspeed squared

Comment: GeV is a unit of energy - it's already been multiplied by $c^2$, you don't need to do it again.

Comment: Oh, I remember that now, Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments, the mass of the bottom quark is 4 GeV and is already in units of energy. This energy can be reached experimentally (e.g., the LHC can reach CoM energy of 12 TeV).